# TED talk embedded videos cut off by sidebar

Tags: embed, videos

I've published a [post](https://www.whatcanwesolve.com/two-ted-talks-for-valentines-day/) on a new WP site which includes two TED talk videos. I used embed codes supported through the Jetpack plugin (e.g. [ted id=2252]). My problem is that the right edge of the videos (such as where the full-screen button would show) are being cut off by my blog's sidebar. I've tried looking through my theme's options and WP settings for a way to keep the videos sized properly so they don't conflict with the taskbar - but I can't find any such options.

I'm starting to reluctantly think I may have to dig into some CSS to fix this, but I'm not sure how to find the right file(s) or exactly what I'll need to add / edit. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are probably looking for a way to make all embedded videos responsive, not just TED videos. PS: third party plugin/theme support is in general [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You could try to modify the question accordingly to avoid close votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I remember when TED videos first [brought me here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82636/26350) to WPSE some time ago :-)*

The global [*content width*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Width) or the *embed size width* option `embed_size_w` might be slightly off on your site.

Alternatively you could manually insert the *width*:

```
[ted id="2252" width="600"]
```

where the *height* is then adjusted to give you the `16x9` aspect ratio.

Note that TED [oEmbed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds#oEmbed) support was added into WordPress 4.0

Comment: Rather than picking a specific pixel count for width, can I use a responsive-friendly option like percentage? I tried doing that earlier but it didn't work, so I figured either my syntax was off...

[ted id="2252" width="80%"]

...or that isn't supported.

Comment: Only numeric widths/heights are supported. [Here's](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/138553/26350) an example for a  responsive workaround.  @JeremyJameson